# RegEx match for thousands currency value

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-validate

I'm using the jquery validation plug-in and have added a method to check for currency.  Here is the method:

```
j$.validator.addMethod("money", function(value, element) {
            return this.optional(element) || /^(\d{1,3})(\.\d{2})$/.test(value);
            //return this.optional(element) || /^((?:\d{1,3},)?\d{1,3})(\.\d{2})$/.test(value);
        }, "Must be in US currency format 0.99");
```

This correctly validates values from 0.00 to 999.99.  But, as soon as I hit 1,000.00 the method will return false.  I'm not very good with regular expressions, but from what I can tell, the regex expression does not match a value that is 1,000.00 or higher?

Can anyone help with how to modify the regex expression to match a currency value for 0.00 up to 999,999.99?  So, it can correctly validate a currency value in the thousands?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: With or without a comma?

Comment: Just remove '^' symbol from the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will validate every range starting from 0.00

```
^\d{1,3}([,]\d{3})*(\.\d{2})$
```

and if you want to have it only to 999,999.99 then use this

```
^\d{1,3}([,]\d{3})?(\.\d{2})$
```

Comment: If the OP only wants to support up to 999,999.99, the `*` should be a `?`.

Comment: I tried the following: ^\d{1,3}([,]\d{3})?(\.\d{2})$ and it failed for 1,000.00.  I do want to validate with commas.  It looks as if the above validate with commas?

Comment: Thanks for the help.  It was my mistake.  Another issue was causing the failure on my part.  The regex is working now.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Try this regex:

```
^\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})?(?:\.\d{2})?$
```

### [Live Demo](http://www.rubular.com/r/xKDtY3TX1Q)

Comment: @Tomas: Oh in that case OP just needs to remove `?` after decimal like this: `^\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})?\.\d{2}$`